# Let $\mathcal{T}_1$ and $\mathcal{T}_2$ be topologies of a space $X$. Are the following claims true?

Tags: general-topology

> Let $\mathcal{T}_1$ and $\mathcal{T}_2$ be topologies of a space $X$. Are the following claims true?
>
> 1. If $(X, \mathcal{T}_1)$ is Hausdorff and $\mathcal{T}_1 \subset \mathcal{T}_2$, then $(X, \mathcal{T}_2)$ is Hausdorff.
> 2. If $(X, \mathcal{T}_1)$ is Hausdorff and $\mathcal{T}_2 \subset \mathcal{T}_1$, then $(X, \mathcal{T}_2)$ is Hausdorff.
> 3. If $(X, \mathcal{T}_1)$ is compact and $\mathcal{T}_1 \subset \mathcal{T}_2$, then $(X, \mathcal{T}_2)$ is compact.
> 4. If $(X, \mathcal{T}_1)$ is compact and $\mathcal{T}_2 \subset \mathcal{T}_1$, then $(X, \mathcal{T}_2)$ is compact.

The first two don't seem to be true. If $(X, \mathcal{T}_1)$ is Hausdorff, then for any $x, y \in (X, \mathcal{T}_1)$ we can find respective neighborhoods $U$ and $V$ that are disjoint, but it could be that $\mathcal{T}_2$ contains open sets for disjoint points that cannot be separated.

The second one I think a counterexample would just be any $\mathcal{T}_1$ Hausdorff and $\mathcal{T}_2 = \{X, \emptyset\}$. Then $(X, \mathcal{T}_2)$ is certainly not Hausdorff.

For $3$ if $\mathcal{C}$ is a $\mathcal{T}_1$-cover for $X$, then there exists a finite $\mathcal{T}_1$-subcover $\mathcal{C}'$ and each element in $\mathcal{C}'$ is also in $\mathcal{T}_2$ so this is likely a true result.

For $4$ if we take $X = [0,1]$ with $\mathcal{T}_1$ the standard topology and $\mathcal{T}_2$ the subspace topology on $\mathbb{Q}$, then $\mathcal{T}_2 \subset \mathcal{T}_1$, but $(X, \mathcal{T}_2)$ is not compact since a rational sequence in $X$ that converges to some irrational point doesn't have a convergent subsequence right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\T}{\mathcal{T}}$I'm not sure why but you seem to have these back to front. Some hints and commentary are given below.

For $(1)$, if $(X;\T_1)$ is Hausdorff and $x,y\in X$ are two distinct points, then we know there are $U,V\in\T_1$ with $x\in U,\,y\in V$ and $U\cap V=\emptyset$. Can we use the same $U$ and $V$ in $(X;\T_2)$? Notice that $\T_2$ is not introducing any new points, only new neighbourhoods.

For $(2)$, your counterexample is correct... *if* $X$ has cardinality greater than $1$. A small detail but one we should still observe.

For $(3)$, you've observed that if $C$ is a $\T_1$-cover of $X$ then $C$ has admits a finite subcover. Sure. But what if $C$ is a $\T_2$-cover of $X$?

For $(4)$, your counterexample is wrong since you haven't changed the topology on $X$ but rather you've changed $X$ itself (replaced $[0,1]$ with $[0,1]\cap\Bbb Q$). Changing only the topology, I ask you: if $C$ is a $\T_2$-cover of $X$, is it a $\T_1$-cover of $X$ too? Can we use that?

Follow-up challenge:

> Show that, if $X$ is any set and $\T$ any topology on $X$ such that $(X;\T)$ is a compact Hausdorff space, then the only comparable topology on $X$, with respect to $\T$, that makes $X$ a compact Hausdorff space is $\T$ itself.
>
> Differently put, show that if you make $\T$ any finer or coarser then $(X;\T)$ is no longer compact Hausdorff.

Comment: +1. To the proposer: It is useful to examine some of the simplest cases to see whether a general  statement is true.  If (3) were true then every topology $\mathcal T_2$ is compact (which of course is false) because if $\mathcal T_1=\{\emptyset, X\}$ then $\mathcal T_1$ is compact and $\mathcal T_1\subseteq\mathcal T_2$

Comment: In $(3)$ I think one could also take $\mathcal{T}_1$ to be the indiscrete topology to obtain a counterexample? @FShrike

Comment: @SleepWalker Yes, as Daniel points out. Take any noncompact topology on $X$ and call it $\mathcal{T}_2$, a refinement of the compact, indiscrete $\mathcal{T}_1$. That $\mathcal{T}_1$ is compact does not imply $\mathcal{T}_2$ is.